# How we can reset statistics in Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I like to monitoring Camel 2.15.2 with Decanter 1.0.0 into Apache Karaf 3.0.3. I get statistics (MaxProcessingTime, LastProcessingTime...) but I can't reset these counters.

How we can reset statistics in Apache Camel?

Comment: Usually to reset counters you have to restart the instance.  Why are you trying to reset the counters could you elaborate on what your trying to do?

Comment: I want to reset counters statistics afters 5 minutes, the problem is i don't know what is the best way?

Comment: Use JMX or the karaf camel commands.

Answer (score 1):

I typically don't recommend resetting the jmx statistics, but you can do that by calling the reset method in the jmx Operations for that particular stat tracker.  If you go to the jsconsole and open up the jmx view and drill down to a particular route or processor under Operations you will find the reset method.

Comment: Its worth noting that this could be done pro-grammatically as well with any utility that allows you to call jmx functions